# ProxyPassReverse dropping HTTPS

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, ubuntu-14.04

On my home network, I have a web server and a DNS server. I have various other application servers that I have added redirects for so I can simply visit sites like `myapplication.domain.com` or `www.domain.com/application` to get to my various services. I have a Subsonic server running on another server, and my goal is to be able to visit `https://subsonic.domain.com` and get my Subsonic traffic served over SSL on my web server. Eventually I hope to access this from outside the home, which is why it's important to proxy the non-secured HTTP traffic over HTTPS, but for right now, I'm just trying to get it working at home.

When I visit `https://subsonic.domain.com`, I end up getting an "unable to connect" error. The address I appear to be redirected to is `subsonic.domain.com/login.view`. If I tack HTTPS onto the front of that URL, I get the login page I'm looking for. Once I log in again, however, the URL changes, I'm redirected, and I end up losing the HTTPS again an have to keep re-adding it. Obviously I am doing something wrong.

I have set up a VirtualHost for `subsonic.domain.com` and am trying to use `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` to get the traffic redirected in the way I want. Here is my VirtualHost for this site:

```
    <VirtualHost subsonic.domain.com:443>

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyErrorOverride Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.5:4040/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.5:4040/

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

    </VirtualHost>
```

SSL is definitely up and running with no problem. I have another identical virtualhost for another directory that works fine (redirects on `https://www.domain.com/directory`), so I'm not sure what the problem is here. After the ProxyPassReverse, the URL just seems to be losing the `https://` part. If I add it in, the site works fine until I visit another page and `https://` is lost again. If I visit the application server directly at `http://192.168.1.5:4040`, I have no issues whatsoever.

Any advice would be most welcome.

**EDIT**

A little clarification on what I'm trying to do. I want to have my Apache server doing all of my redirecting and handling all of my SSL requests. Basically, from the browser to the Apache server is HTTPS, the `ProxyPass` from the Apache server to the application server us unencrypted HTTP (which is fine, this is my internal network), the `ProxyPassReverse` from the application server to the Apache server is plain HTTP, then the Apache server sends out the traffic as HTTPS.

Here's another VirtualHost that does what I want for a different subdomain. This is tested and works 100%. I connect to my Apache server via HTTPS, the Apache server contacts my ownCloud server in plain old HTTP, the response to my Apache server is plain HTTP, then the Apache server returns the request in HTTPS to the browser:

```
<VirtualHost www.domain.com:443>

            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

            ProxyRequests Off
            ProxyErrorOverride Off
            ProxyPreserveHost On

            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

            ProxyPass /owncloud/ http://192.168.1.251/owncloud/
            ProxyPassReverse /owncloud/ http://192.168.1.251/owncloud/

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            SSLEngine on

            SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your subsonic backend doesn't send encrypted traffic already, does it? I'm confused because I can't think why you'd want to specify different protocols on `ProxyPass` and `-Reverse` .

Comment: No, the Subsonic back end serves up plain HTTP. I'm not trying to specify different protocols for the ProxyPass and the Reverse, from what I understand they both should be HTTP. I'll post my other virtualhost when I get a minute. It is nearly identical to the one above. It passes HTTP from the application server and sends it out as  HTTPS.

Comment: I think you'd want `http://` on both ProxyPass and -Reverse then, and SSL will be stripped at the Apache layer.

Comment: I believe that's correct, that is how it works on my other VirtualHost. I just edited my original post to show an example of this working and clarification on what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ulrich, sorry for the confusion, I did not realize I had `https://` in the Reverse in my post. I had the `https://` on the reverse for testing purposes but had since removed it. Even with `http://` on the ProxyPass and the Reverse, it still does not work. I have edited my original post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So I ran into this problem as well and while commenting out `ProxyPreserveHost` fixes the problem with the configuration above, there is a better way.

The `ProxyPass`<sup>[1](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)</sup> statement tells Apache to take an incoming request on the URI and pass it through to the specified host. With `ProxyPreserveHost On`, Apache does not change the **Host:** HTTP header and passes the request unmodified. (By default it changes it to match the backend host specified in the `ProxyPass` statement).

The `ProxyPassReverse`<sup>[2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse)</sup> statement tells Apache to match the host specified with the **Host:** header on the outgoing response and if it matches to adjust the **Location:**, **Content-Location:**, and **URI:** headers to match the VirtualHost or more specifically what Apache thinks is the canonical name.

So with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost subsonic.domain.com:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.5:4040/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.5:4040/
</VirtualHost>
```

This is taking a request:

`https://subsonic.domain.com/` -> `http://192.168.1.5:4040/`

but since `ProxyPreserveHost` is on, it is leaving the **Host:** header in the request intact as `subsonic.domain.com`

Your web application is most likely sending a response from `subsonic.domain.com` but that does not match the `ProxyPassReverse` rule you have specified:

`http://subsonic.domain.com/` <- `http://subsonic.domain.com/`

So the configuration:

```
<VirtualHost subsonic.domain.com:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.5:4040/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://subsonic.domain.com/ # Changed to match canonical host
</VirtualHost>
```

This rule should match the replies coming from the proxy host.

Comment: Thank you very much, this kind of detailed response is exactly the clarification I was looking for. Since my configuration is working for the time being, I will not modify, but since for some reason the config breaks every few months without me doing anything, this will be a useful resource.

Comment: Thanks this saved my day ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the second line, too. (The proxied host had ServerAlias which I did not account for.) The short version of the answer is: **account for all known server names**.

Answer (score 4):

In my VirtualHost for Subsonic, I had to disable the `ProxyPreserveHost On` directive. I can now access the site externally and internally.

For some reason, this worked fine for my other VirtualHost, but for this one it did not. I'm assuming it's because in my one VirtualHost, the ProxyPass is working on a directory and not a hostname. In my VirtualHost for Subsonic, I don't specify a directory.

To anyone that actually knows what they're talking about in regards to Apache, VirtualHosts, redirects, etc, please feel free to clarify if I'm not describing accurately what's going on.

Here is my VirtualHost for anyone else that is experiencing this same issue.

```
    <VirtualHost subsonic.domain.com:443>

        #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        #RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyErrorOverride Off
        #ProxyPreserveHost On - This line now commented out

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.5:4040/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.5:4040/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

</VirtualHost>
```